# stuck with Stripe Checkout

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm new to using stripe. I am able to process payment within test mode. but I keep receiving a lot of console log errors. One of which is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined" I have three payment I am setting up as options which are sent to my server where the charge is being made. I've seen where some have used "closed:" in their stripecheckout.configure but it is not working for me.

```js
const stripePK = 'pk_test_key';



var handlerGold = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: stripePK,
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  zipCode: true,
  billingAddress: true,
  token: function(token, args) {
    console.log('this is tokens', token)
    console.log('this is args', args)
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/charge/gold', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer' + stripePK
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(token, args)
      })
      .then(output => {
        console.log(output)
        if (output.status === "succeeded")
          document.getElementById("shop").innerHTML = "<p>Purchase complete!</p>";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.status === 400) {
          console.log('Bad request, often due to missing a required parameter.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 401) {
          console.log('No valid API key provided.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 404) {
          console.log('The requested resource doesn\'t exist.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 500) {
          console.log('Purchase Failed', error)
        }
      })

  }
});

var handlerPurple = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: stripePK,
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  zipCode: true,
  billingAddress: true,
  token: function(token, args) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/charge/purple', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer' + stripePK
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(token, args)
      })
      .then(output => {
        if (output.status === "succeeded")
          document.getElementById("shop").innerHTML = "<p>Purchase complete!</p>";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.status === 400) {
          console.log('Bad request, often due to missing a required parameter.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 401) {
          console.log('No valid API key provided.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 404) {
          console.log('The requested resource doesn\'t exist.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 500) {
          console.log('Purchase Failed', error)
        }
      })

  }
});

var handlerWhite = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: stripePK,
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  closed: function() {
    if (!token_triggered) {
      // close button click behavior goes here
      console.log("closed")
    } else {
      // payment completion behavior goes here
      console.log("passed")
    }
  },
  locale: 'auto',
  zipCode: true,
  billingAddress: true,
  token: function(token, args) {
    token_triggered = true;
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/charge/white', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer' + stripePK
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(token, args)
      })
      .then(output => {
        if (output.status === "succeeded")
          document.getElementById("shop").innerHTML = "<p>Purchase complete!</p>";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.status === 400) {
          console.log('Bad request, often due to missing a required parameter.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 401) {
          console.log('No valid API key provided.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 404) {
          console.log('The requested resource doesn\'t exist.', error);
        } else if (error.status === 500) {
          console.log('Purchase Failed', error)
        }
      })

  }
});


//GOLD PACKAGE BUTTON
document.getElementById('goldButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handlerGold.open({
    name: 'PMM Picnic',
    description: 'Gold Package',
    amount: 2000,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

//PURPLE PACKAGE BUTTON
document.getElementById('purpleButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handlerPurple.open({
    name: 'PMM Picnic',
    description: 'Purple Package',
    amount: 1000,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

//WHITE PACKAGE BUTTON
document.getElementById('whiteButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handlerWhite.open({
    name: 'PMM Picnic',
    description: 'White Package(Student & Staff Only)',
    amount: 700,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});


// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handlerGold.close();
});
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handlerPurple.close();
});
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handlerWhite.close();
});

//END STRIPE
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- registration for the events currently 3 options payment may be set up through strip or find a way to send to cashapp account -->
<div class="price-area" id="registration">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title-default">Ticket Price & Plan</h1>
    <p class="sub-title-default">Here you can purchase your ticket and wristbands for the event and skip the lines</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" container plan">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="price-box1 price-box-hover">
          <span>White Package</span>
          <h2>$7</h2>
          <h3>per current band member & staff only </h3>
          <p>Free Food</p>
          <p>Free Drinks(Regular)</p>
          <p>Unlimited Prizes</p>
          <div id="shop">
            <button class="payButton" id="whiteButton">Order Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="price-box2 price-box-hover">
          <span>Purple Package</span>
          <h2>$10</h2>
          <h3>per person</h3>
          <p>Free Food</p>
          <p>Free Drinks(Regular)</p>
          <p>Unlimited Prizes</p>
          <div id="shop">
            <button class="payButton" id="purpleButton">Order Now</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="price-box3 price-box-hover">
          <span>Gold Package</span>
          <h2>$20</h2>
          <h3>per person</h3>
          <p>Free Food</p>
          <p>Free Drinks(Any)</p>
          <p>Unlimited Prizes</p>
          <div id="shop">
            <button class="payButton" id="goldButton">Order Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of price boxes -->

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're seeing `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined"` that means the handler you are trying to close does not exist. I also might take a step back, you could create a single instance of checkout with `StripeCheckout.configure` set up a listener for on click for each of your buttons, adjust the `open` call as appropriate, populate variables or hidden `<input>`s in your form. http://jsfiddle.net/cvu60dff/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried this way and it does work. the problem comes when the data is sent to the server. stripe does not have a way of sending the amount the customer chooses to the server. so I did a POST request to send the data and have it triggered with different URLs(i.e. /gold, /purple etc)

Comment: In your onClick you could set the value of a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="product" value="gold" />` (or a JS var if making an AJAX request like above), then when the form is submitted this value would be passed to your endpoint, you could look up the product on your backend!